# Read url and show right results

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Can someone help me with this code.

Now it is working like this.

If url is

```
www.example.com/dc.html?dc=apples
```

Then show

```
"I like Apples"
```

I want to show the result like above, when url is

```
www.example.com/dc-Apples.html
```

Means If the HTML `url` contain `apple` then it should show

```
"I like Apples"
```

Here is the code I have now.
..............................................................................................................................................

```
 <style>
    .dynamic-content {
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Parse the URL parameter
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    // Give the parameter a variable name
    var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('dc');

     $(document).ready(function() {

        // Check if the URL parameter is apples
        if (dynamicContent == 'apples') {
            $('#apples').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parameter is oranges
        else if (dynamicContent == 'oranges') {
            $('#oranges').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parameter is bananas
        else if (dynamicContent == 'bananas') {
            $('#bananas').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parmeter is empty or not defined, display default content
        else {
            $('#default-content').show();
        }
    });
</script>
<!-- Default Dynamic Section -->
<div id="default-content" class="dynamic-content">
  This is the default content
</div>
<!-- Dynamic Section 1 -->
<div id="apples" class="dynamic-content">
  I like apples
</div>
<!-- Dynamic Section 2 -->
<div id="oranges" class="dynamic-content">
  I like oranges
</div>
<!-- Dynamic Section 3 -->
<div id="bananas" class="dynamic-content">
  I like bananas
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to change the url?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/979997

Comment: What are the conditions for matching? Is `example.com/a/bdc-Apples.gif` OK? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It only works when i type the url like this

www.example.com/dc.html?dc=apples

Comment: What i want it do is read the url and if the url contain "apple" then write "I like apples" on that site.

I will put this in the header so it will be applied to all pages I have, all pages that contain "apples" in the name then "I like apple" should show.

Comment: does your `url` have to be like `www.example.com/dc-Apple.html` ? and if the page (`dc-Apple.html`) does not exist and you are not using any routing mechanisms to handle it than the proposed `url` will not work then your only option would be to either do it by `Query Parameter` or create an additional page (if you don't have any route handling mechanisam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When browser request `www.example.com/dc-Apples.html` URL to the server, then the server will look for `dc-Apples.html` file. So you need to create `dc-Apples.html` file. Since your URL is dynamic, it is not possible to handle dynamic URL only with jQuery.

In order to handle dynamic URL, you need to use server-side coding like `.php`, `asp.net`, `.htaccess`

Below I have used `.htaccess` and `.php` to solve your question.

In .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+).html dc.php?dc=$1 [NC,L]
```

In dc.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['dc'])){
        $dc_value = explode("-",$_GET['dc']);
        $dc_value[1] = strtolower($dc_value[1]);
    }else{
        echo "can't get parameter";
        die();
    }
?>

<?php if($dc_value[1] == "apples"): ?>
    <div id="apples" class="dynamic-content">
        I like apples
    </div>
<?php elseif($dc_value[1] == "oranges"): ?>
    <div id="oranges" class="dynamic-content">
        I like oranges
    </div>
<?php elseif($dc_value[1] == "bananas"): ?>
    <div id="bananas" class="dynamic-content">
        I like bananas
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div id="default-content" class="dynamic-content">
        This is the default content
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now it will works, when you call `www.example.com/dc-Apples.html`, it will display "I like apples"

Comment: Wow. That was a nice solution. Works great. Thanks.

Comment: Great, If it works, then you can accept my answer as solved. @CharlieCarver

Comment: I added 

$dc_value[1] = substr(0, 6);

to dc.php
So the even if its "appl" Then show "I like apples"

But not working. Can you help me with that to thanks.

Comment: Try to change if condition `<?php if($dc_value[1] == "apples" || $dc_value[1] == "appl") : ?>`

Comment: Thanks m8.
I try make this work when a link is
www.example.com/jskkskAppleSomething.html

want the script recognise the the word apple. Now if the url is only apples then that messages show.

Answer (score 0):

best solution [here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html)
also you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903119/5306340) 
according to this solution you must get parameter value with implemented function and doing whatever you want.